# ASP.NET MVC 5 CS0234 Type of namespace does not exist

Tags: c#-4.0, razor, compiler-errors, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm having some trouble with an Helper/Extension class I made. When trying to use it in my razor view I get

> Compiler Error CS0234. The type or namespace name 'name' does not exist in the namespace 'namespace' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I have a MVC 5 web project where I have a class library (which works as an addon) containing my UI controllers and views. The view was rendering and my controller action is executing.

When I do @using my_project.UI.Navigation, I get compiler error CS0234. Later in my view I have a call to @NavigationHelper.BuildHtml() (which full is in my_project.UI.Navigation).

But my controller can execute just fine:

```
@using my_project.UI.Navigation

namespace my_project.Controllers
{
    public UiController : IController
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var test = NavigationHelper.BuildHtml();
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

both classes and namespaces are in the same assembly.